# Selecting Document Library through PropertyPane in SPFX

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, spfx-custom-property-pane

Here is the description about web part:

Both web parts are same and only one ,only changed the heading and labels and their input's ID through property pane.

One Webpart is working fine on a page ,but when uploading multiple webpart getting issues.

But on the click of first webpart input fields , getting the value on the second Webpart.

Selecting Different Input id for both webpart through propertyPane.

[image]

Here is the property pane of my webpart which is same for both webpart but selected different value for property pane of both webpart.

Getting Folders on the basis of DocumentLibrary selected in the property pane as well as documentType's value is also getting from property pane.

I am getting value of folder as well as documentType on the double click on the folder's input as well as documentType input respectively.

[image]

Comment: Are you performing any DOM manipulation operations in your web part, based on id/class of HTML elements? If yes, you should have unique id for all HTML elements.

Comment: Yes i was performing DOM manipulation  operations on the basis of ID and all the ID are unique as they are selected through Property Pane but dont know why i getting value on another webpart when performing onclick event on first webpart

Comment: Maybe HTML elements in both the web parts has same IDs. Those are separated web parts, but at the end both are on same page/DOM. so, those are not unique at DOM level.

Comment: So , is there any way to use both webpart on the same page without any conflicts

Comment: Are using react web part or no JS web part? Avoid DOM manipulations using IDs or if you are using react, handle data show/hide based on react "state".

Comment: Yes i am using react framework to build this webpart but new in react

Comment: Then you can utilize the react concepts in your web part. check SPFx samples link in my answer which will help you to understand how others are using react with SPFx. Or if you want to do DOM manipulation then you have to create unique element IDs somehow.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of behavior happens when you perform DOM manipulation in your web part like using ID or class of HTML element and change its attributes to show/hide the controls or to display the data in your web part.

As you are using React, you can use your TSX component to render the data in place, without DOM manipulation. You can also store your results in your component's `state` and call `this.setState()` to update your elements when you update the state. You can also use the React `ref` attribute to create a reference to an element and set it's value later.

If you must use DOM manipulation, consider using an approach that will make your element IDs unique.

**Reference**: [Adding same webpart with different configuration, multiple times on the same page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/272094/adding-same-webpart-with-different-configuration-multiple-times-on-the-same-pag)

You can also refer to the SPFx samples created by community members using react to learn how you can use react with SPFx web parts: [SPFx web part samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples)

Comment: Hi Abhishek, does this answer help you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.